# Cannot find Command Editor in DB2 Express-C

Tags: database, db2

I installed DB2 Express-C latest edition in my system. After installation, i cannot find any Command Editor/Control Center. All i can see is a command editor. Is it like i have to execute my queries using that command editor without any user friendly UI such as command editor or some other UI ?

Please suggest

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got v10.1 (which I'm assuming you are, since you say "latest edition"), then those applications were deprecated in favor of [IBM Data Studio](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/data/).

You should download and install Data Studio if you want to use a GUI with DB2 v10.

Comment: Without Data Studio, how can i connect to a database using command?

Comment: There's always the [command line](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0503melnyk/).  Or you can search for another GUI that supports DB2.  I use Data Studio, so I don't know any of those. :)